# Is there a way to get all Magento Attribute Codes and Values into One Array In One Call?

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I am running a script on a server to retrieve all products from a Magento store and then split it out into a specific feed format for use in a shopping engine.

The problem is coming when getting the attributes and their values (for example, colour, size etc.).

This particular store has 24 different attributes types and 1300 products and each time I am running the script it is bringing the CPU load of the server up to around 97% and this has only happened since I added in the functionality to retrieve Product Attribute Codes and Values.

The call I'm using for getting each Attribute Value is, for example the following:

`$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('bed_size')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); 
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('bowl_size')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('cage_size')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); 
$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('coat_size')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);`
This works fine for all the products with a few attributes, but it has major issues when I start dealing with all 24 attributes (don't ask me why they have so many, and no, unfortunately I have no control over changing/consolidating these into less).

I need to know if there is a way of loading all a products attributes and values into one initial array and then using PHP to do the processing work for me.

I'm not 100% sure on how Magento works in terms of retrieving this data but it would seem to me that each `->getValue($_product)` call is calling the database to retrieve the attribute value making excessive load on the database system.

If this is correct then this would result in 24 * 1300 database calls each time I run the script giving me a total of 31,200 calls in just over a minute.

If I could reduce this to one database call per product for all attributes then deal with the results using arrays in PHP then the load on the server I expect would become manageable but as I said, not understanding 100% how Magento processes this information it's hard for me to ascertain.

As a side note, I am running the same script on another site with only 3 attributes and a similar amount of products and it has never had any issues such as these.

I could use the following for getting the bed size value `$_product->getBedSize`, however this returns the numeric option value, I believe because this is a select box type attribute value and not a text box or textarea type, not the text value which is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohh, you are getting values of all the attributes ONE-BY-ONE?

Better use the below script to get all attribute values and store it in an array with "attribute name" as keys!

```
$attrValues = array();
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) {
        $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        $attrValues[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($attrValues);
```

Comment: Perfect Kalpesh... thankyou! I knew there must be a better way of doing this!